# return only duplicated values in multidimentional array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to get only duplicated records in multidimentional array.
My array looks like:

```
"items": [
 {
  "id": "1",
  "father_name": "YYY",
  "surname": "XXX",
  "name": "abc",
 },
 {
  "id": "1",
  "father_name": "YYY",
  "surname": "XXX",
  "name": "abc",
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "father_name": "ZZZ",
  "surname": "UUU",
  "name": "abc",
 },
]
```

I want to get results like

```
"items": [
   {
      "id": "1",
      "father_name": "YYY",
      "surname": "XXX",
      "name": "abc",
   },
]
```

How can I get it? Please help me I am stuck here.

I have tried many things but everything works in single dimensional array

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: the presented array doesn't look like a PHP output, it comes from a JSON string?

Comment: which key values you want to consider to get the duplicate array result ? all keys or any particular key(s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given data is a json string.

Assuming the same for your array structure try this:

```
$arr = array("items"=>array(
  "id"=> "1",
  "father_name"=> "YYY",
  "surname"=> "XXX",
  "name"=> "abc",
 ),
 array(
  "id"=> "1",
  "father_name"=> "YYY",
  "surname"=> "XXX",
  "name"=> "abc",
 ),
 array(
  "id"=> "2",
  "father_name"=> "ZZZ",
  "surname"=> "UUU",
  "name"=> "abc",
 )
);

$withoutDuplicates = array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
$duplicates = array_diff_assoc($arr, $withoutDuplicates);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($duplicates);
```

OUTPUT:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 1
>               [father_name] => YYY
>               [surname] => XXX
>               [name] => abc
>           ))

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in line 24

Comment: @AndrewLarsen sorry but i'm not getting any.

Comment: What php version are you running? I got this notice when testing it on php 5.6.25

Comment: yes it's giving me error too like @AndrewLarsen said
but this code works if I set display_errors to OFF

Comment: I must say, that out of all answers, Ross Wilson is the one providing a working efficient solution without any warnings appearing.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to other answers you could also do something like:

```
$duplicates = [];

while ($a = array_shift($array)) {
    if (in_array($a, $array) && !in_array($a, $duplicates)) {
        $duplicates[] = $a;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Best solution here so far.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    'items' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'father_name' => 'YYY',
            'surname' => 'XXX',
            'name' => 'abc'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'father_name' => 'YYY',
            'surname' => 'XXX',
            'name' => 'abc'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'father_name' => 'ZZZ',
            'surname' => 'UUU',
            'name' => 'abc'
        )
    )
);

$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr['items'])-1; $i++) {
    for ($x = $i+1; $x < count($arr['items']); $x++) {
        if ($arr['items'][$i] !== $arr['items'][$x] || in_array($arr['items'][$i], $result))
            continue;

        array_push($result, $arr['items'][$i]);
    }
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

One way to go at it, assuming you are working with multi-dimensional php arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach($items as $key => $item)
{
   unset($items[$key]);
   if(array_search($item['id'], array_column($items, 'id_or_another_key')))
   {
        $result[] = $item;
   }
}
```

The sense of this code is next:

1. You should go through the initial array in the cycle
2. Delete the current item from the array
3. Search the similar items by the 'id' value or by the another key between the rest elements
4. If the item was found, you put it to the result array with duplicated items.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * @param $data array
 * 
 * @return array
 */
function getDuplicatesOnly(array $data): array
{
    $result = [
            'items' => [
                ],
        ];
    foreach ($data as $key => $datum) {
        $itemId = $datum['id'];
        unset($data[$key]);
        $columns = array_column($data, 'id');
        if(in_array($itemId, $columns)) {
           $result['items'][] = $datum;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

 $testData = [
        'input' => [
            'items' => [
                [
                    'id' => '1',
                    'father_name' => 'YYY',
                    'surname' => 'XXX',
                    'name' => 'abc'
                ],
                [
                    'id' => '1',
                    'father_name' => 'YYY',
                    'surname' => 'XXX',
                    'name' => 'abc'
                ],
                [
                    'id' => '2',
                    'father_name' => 'ZZZ',
                    'surname' => 'UUU',
                    'name' => 'abc'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'output' => [
                'items' => [
                        [
                            'id' => '1',
                            'father_name' => 'YYY',
                            'surname' => 'XXX',
                            'name' => 'abc'
                        ]
                    ],
            ],
    ];   

$output = getDuplicatesOnly($testData['input']['items']);
assert($testData['output'] == $output, "Failed asserting data.");
```

Can be tested [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/421330e8a980c6285a53dffa5053e80228392047).